# How to move all files and folders from one Directory to other in PHP?

Tags: file, copy, move, directory

I have directory structure like below

Test

- test1

  - test 1.1
  - test 1.2
    -sample1

    - sample2
  - test 1.3
  - test 1.4

I am trying to move All files and folders from test1 to Test. How this can be achieved in Php?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use a directory iterator and the [php `rename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) function?

i.e

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('Test/test1');
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        rename(
            'Test/test1/'.$fileinfo->getFileName(),
            'Test/'.$fileinfo->getFileName(),
        );
    }
}
```

I have not tested this code and it's provided only as an example. You'll need to modify to deal with moving subfolders ect.